# gtest comparison between enum and object

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

I have problem using

```
EXPECT_EQ(expected, actual)
```

I have a a situation when **expected** is enum and **actual** is some object.

this object has overloading for operator == with this enum, but the problem it performs
`if (expected == actual)` and not `if (actual == expected)`, so trying to use the enum as the lhs is wrong, is there a way to "override" this? I tried to do some stuff with specilized templates,
but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the symmetric comparison as a non-member function:

```
bool operator==(my_enum e, my_object const & o) {return o == e;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the `operator==` a non-member the lefthand operand can be your enumerated type instead of the class type.